# Need help fixing the plot for a simple curve() function code

Tags: r

I am trying to plot four separate functions on the same graph using the `curve()` function in r. I came up with the following code:

`for (n in 1:4){
  curve(n*sin(x), -5, 5, add = TRUE)
 }`

Unfortunately, when I try that, the resulting plot is extremely zoomed in on one arbitrary point of the graph (axes labels nor graph borders can be seen either). Just to clarify, there is no resulting error message in the console at all, the plot is just very zoomed in.

Instead of plotting them in a for loop, I tried plotting them separately to see if it would work and it did. I used:

`curve(4*sin(x), -5, 5)
 curve(3*sin(x), -5, 5, add = TRUE)
 curve(2*sin(x), -5, 5, add = TRUE)
 curve(1*sin(x), -5, 5, add = TRUE)`

I had also thought that it could be that I used `curve()` in a `for` loop; however, it has worked for this code (demonstrating that the function doesn't seem to care whether I use it in a loop-type function):

`for (n in 0:5){
  curve(x^n, -3, 3, add = TRUE)
 }`

Besides trying out different code, I have closed my graphics device, turned it off with `dev.off()`, restarted RStudio, but none of it has worked.

If I were only using a sequence from 1 to 4, like I mentioned above, I wouldn't care about typing them separately; however, I plan on using a much larger range of sequences in the future (like 1:50 or 1:100 for example).

I'm using RStudio version 3.4.4 with macOS 10.14.2 if that matters.

Comment: @李哲源 So I actually tried that too, as I figured that it was a y-axis formatting issue; however, this didn't work either. Also, the graph is zoomed in for both the x- and y-axes.

Comment: THIS WORKED! Thank you so much! I have no idea why calling `dev.off()` worked when it was on the same line as the for function, but it did! It also worked for all other sequences of numbers! Thank you so much again!